# Checking multiple columns for NULL

Tags: postgresql

With Postgresql, how can I find if any columns in a table have null values (I want to check all columns together)? Is there a way to scan the entire table for NULL and determine which columns have a null, and display the rows with at least one null value?

[image: My columns]

`select * from mpe where company isnull`;
gives nothing, i.e. there is no NULL in company column. But if I write `SELECT * FROM mpe WHERE num_nulls(company, city, st, dbas) > 0;` I get company column in the result although has no NULL. I want to see only columns in my result that have NULL and their respective rows that hold those NULL values.

Comment: You'll have to type out all the columns that you want to check. The query is rather straightforward: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col_a IS NULL OR col_b IS NULL OR col_c IS NULL OR …;`

Comment: Or to save a bit of typing: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE num_nulls(col_a, col_b, col_c, …) > 0;`

Comment: You can get a list of columns in the table from [information_schema.columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/infoschema-columns.html), and then use that in a function to create a query. [Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/BnI8aJYo). *However*, your question hints at a schema problem. Maybe a single table with col1, col2, col3 that should be turned into a join table? Perhaps you could show us what you're trying to solve by checking all columns for null?

Comment: @Bergi: Your second comment is closer, but not exactly what I wanted. I am going to edit my question for clarification.

Comment: @RamseyA. you cannot (and should not) write sql that dynamically chooses which columns to return. If you really needed that, you'd need to do multiple queries, one to find out which columns contain null values, and then one with dynamically built sql to select only those columns.

Comment: @RamseyA. Also it's rather unclear what you mean by "*I want to see columns […] and their respective rows*". How do you identify a "row" if you only get the columns where every value is `NULL`??? It would really help if you could add some example data to your question and the output you expect for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the row to a JSONB value and check if it's the same after removing nulls:

```
select *
from the_table t
where to_jsonb(t) <> jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(t))
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/TnwcxGPa)